# Predicting the outcome of PHP rand() function given a seeded value

Tags: php, random, srand, lcg

Recently I've been getting into the whole idea of LCGs and Pseudorandom number generators. Anyway, I though that PHP should be a good starting point.

My question is, given a seeded number (done through `srand()` ) how does one predict the next number in the `rand()` sequence?

From what I understand the function should be something like `(SEED * A + C) mod M` How can I find the values of A, C, and M? And if I find those values, can I predict the next number in the sequence?

EDIT: Prior to version 7.0 where rand() becomes an alias of mt_rand()

Comment: *"How can I find the values of A, C, and M"* -- you can find them in the [source code of PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src).

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_rand.h